# Long table to wide table with duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape2

I have a questionnaire applied to a group of subjects. Some questions are single choice, while some are multiple choice. They are stored in a data.frame like the first one shown (User ID, Question ID, Answer ID):

```
usua_rut preg_codigo resp_correlativo
   1           1                1
   2           1                2
   3           1                1
   4           1                2
   5           1                1
   1           2                1
   1           2                2
   2           2                2
   2           2                3
   3           2                3
   4           2                3
   5           2                4
```

Here is the code to create it:

```
data.plot<-data.frame(usua_rut=c(1:5,1,1,2,2,3:5),
                      preg_codigo=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,7)),
                      resp_correlativo=c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4))
```

The idea is to have a data.frame like the following to plot the results:

```
  usua_rut preg_codigo.1  preg_codigo.2
      1           1            1+2
      2           2            2+3
      3           1             3
      4           2             3
      5           1             4
```

In this case, and to keep the same number of respondants in all our plots, we need to create new "artificial" categories (e.g. "1+2") for the second question. We will use the second question as a grouping factor in the barplot of the first one.

I have tried with `dcast` but the `sum` agregator does that: it sums. So, instead of `1+2` I have `3`. I have used the `aggregate` function, but it only works one `preg_codigo` at a time.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to use dplyr mutate function? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/mutate

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel. I saw it, but what `mutate` does is only adding columns. I cannot see how it might help.

Comment: Fyi, you refer to "answers", but most here don't read Spanish (?) and recognize abbreviation "resp", though there is https://es.stackoverflow.com/about You might also want to explain more clearly why your desired results look like that.

Comment: Certanily, Frank, my mistake. This is a questionnaire applied to a group of subjects. Some questions are single choice, while some are multiple choice. They are stored in a data.frame like the first one shown: User ID, Question ID, Answer ID. The idea is to have a data.frame like the second one to plot the results. In this case, and to keep the same number of respondants in all our plots, we need to create new "artificial" categories for the second question. We will use the second question as a grouping factor in the barplot of the first one. Hope the problem is now clear.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it now. Fyi, I did not see your message earlier since you need to use @name when there are multiple commenters. I think you're looking for `dcast(data.plot, usua_rut ~ preg_codigo, fun.agg = paste, collapse="+")` ?

Comment: Exactly @Frank! It is the `collapse="+"` that I was missing. Can you post your suggestion as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty answer based on `aggregate`:

```
df1<-aggregate(resp_correlativo ~ usua_rut, FUN = paste, collapse = 
               "+", data = filter(data.plot,preg_codigo==1))
df2<-aggregate(resp_correlativo ~ usua_rut, FUN = paste, collapse = 
               "+", data = filter(data.plot,preg_codigo==2))
df<-cbind(df1,df2[,2])
colnames(df)<-c("UserID","Question1","Question2")
```

Nevertheless, I was trying to get an out-of-the-box function to achieve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Using dcast from the reshape2 package:

```
dcast(data.plot, usua_rut ~ preg_codigo, fun.agg = paste, collapse="+")

  usua_rut 1   2
1        1 1 1+2
2        2 2 2+3
3        3 1   3
4        4 2   3
5        5 1   4
```